# Im aware this is for programming only

Tags: wifi

I have come accross a situation that does not need to talk about programming but I need this answered on a stackoverflow site. My question is that when a wifi network is in a house hold , do the wifi users need to be disconnected from the wifi network in order for the one desired machine to be used properly with out it being slowed down or does it not matter how many machines are connected. Can any one answer this please looking for reasonable advice..

Comment: Is there a reason this must be answered on StackOverflow even though it's an off-topic question?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the bandwidth you pay for, it's possible that multiple machines in use will cause each machine to have a slower internet connection.

If you think of the internet like a series of pipes, then the bandwidth you're paying for is the throughput of the pipe connection to your wifi. Let's say your pipe connection can push through 10 oz of water per second. If a youtube video is requesting 2 oz of water per second, and you have 3 devices watching youtube videos, then you're using 6oz of water per second and shutting off any one device won't affect the other devices. If you have 10 devices all trying to watch youtube videos at the same time, then you're requesting 20 oz of water per second when the pipe can only provide 10, so at least some devices will be slower. (It depends on your actual router for how that affects your devices. Perhaps each device gets 1 oz per second instead of 2, or else perhaps 5 devices get 2 oz per second and 5 devices get nothing).

I used water as an example because it's easier to visualize, but your internet connection will actually be measured in some multiple of bytes per second (kilobytes per second, megabytes per second, gigabytes per second, etc.). Also, most devices don't require a steady stream of data to work. It all depends on your specific setup: how much data each device is requesting and how much data throughput your internet service provider is giving you.